# Cannot find resource named 'UndockArrowBrush'

Tags: c#, xaml, vsix

I try to add a hidden control to TFSPendingChanges with this XAML definition

```
<UserControl
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      Visibility="Hidden"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      x:Class="VSExtensions.IntegrationSectionView"
      x:Name="IntegrationSection"
      d:DesignWidth="39" d:DesignHeight="39">
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Visibility="Hidden">
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I run Visual Studio it throw this error :

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.. 
>   ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'UndockArrowBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive.

What is missing ?

Comment: I dont think there is anything missing . can you start a new instance of VS and create a blank project and run it and see if it compiles?

Comment: The project compile but throw exception at execution time

Comment: can you reinstall your Visual Studio. I dont think there is any problem with th e code